# Unable to solve “You must specify an orderBy clause when using this function” error by adding orderBy and using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to edit my data in chunks using a job queue.

```
local.ERROR: You must specify an orderBy clause when using this function. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): You must specify an orderBy clause when using this function.
```

I've added orderBy in this handle function of the job class, but the error stays.

```
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        DB::table("posts")->orderBy('id')->where("created_at", "=", null)->chunk(10, function ($posts) {
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                DB::table("posts")->orderBy('id')->where("id", $post->id)->update(["created_at" => now(), "updated_at" => now()]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've also tried using Eloquent Model  like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782083/erroryou-must-specify-an-orderby-clause-when-using-this-function)

```
public function handle(): void
    {
        Post::where("created_at", "=", null)->chunk(10, function ($posts) {
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                Post::where("id", $post->id)->update(["created_at" => now(), "updated_at" => now()]);
            }
        });
    }
```

But no matter how, the error didn't go away, and it didn't even change at all.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not sure if correct, but maybe put your `orderBy` at the end of the chain ?

Comment: After `chunk()`, like `chunk()->orderBy()`? It returns `Expected type 'object'. Found 'bool'.` warning.

Comment: here `DB::table("posts")->orderBy('id')->where("id", $post->id)->update(["created_at" => now(), "updated_at" => now()]);`

Comment: It returns `Expected type 'object'. Found 'int'.` instead.

Comment: How about adding `desc` or `asc` after the `id` like `->orderBy('id', 'desc')` ?

Comment: Not working. The error isn't affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet and let know if it works.

```
DB::table("posts")->whereNUll("created_at")
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->chunk(10, function (Collection $posts) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
       DB::table("posts")->where("id", $post->id)
       ->update(["created_at" => now(), "updated_at" => now()]);
    }
 });
```